# Regex - grab everything between tag (including the tag)

Tags: regex

I've been battling a couple things all day, and my brain is no longer functioning.

I am using this as a string `"something <strong>here</strong>"` and trying t ograb this out of it: `<strong>here</strong>`

How can I do this? I thought string.scan(/(?<=)(.*?)(=</strong>)/) would work but apparently not. Doing this in ruby btw.

Comment: First, read the [mandatory disclaimer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814). If you still want to use regex after that, then the simplest patten is `<strong.*?>.*?</strong>`, but it will fail in **many** cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation.  We need to LEARN not just have code handed to us.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you're not escaping the slash in ?

```
1.9.3-p547 :012 > my_string = "something <strong>here</strong> something else <strong>another thing</strong>"
 => "something <strong>here</strong> something else <strong>another thing</strong>"
1.9.3-p547 :013 > my_string.scan(/(<strong>)(.*?)(<\/strong>)/)
 => [["<strong>", "here", "</strong>"], ["<strong>", "another thing", "</strong>"]]
```

Edit: This grabs it into a single element.

```
my_string.scan(/<strong>.*?<\/strong>/)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this would work. It looks like my original question got a bit screwed up since I tried to insert HTML without wrapping it, but I get the point now after reading your example. Thanks